# How to combine node express with passport providers and jwt?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, jwt

I'm writing a single page web app using `express` and `react`.
I am now trying to choose the way to authenticate my users.
I want to let them register and log in with email and password and 3rd party provider like Facebook, Google etc...

I read some articles about `passport` and `jwt` ([express-with-passport](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local), [jwt-with-passport](https://blog.hyphe.me/token-based-authentication-with-node/)), but none of them combined `jwt` and 3rd party provider.

The only way I could think of is to save the tokens in my db, and for each request to compare them (tokens provided by a 3rd party and tokens generated by myself using `jwt`)

Saving the token from a provider in my db and compare with each request makes sense, but using `jwt` I just need to verify the token without accessing the db.
How can I differ the tokens that I receive from the client? How can I tell when to access the db (for provider tokens) and when to verify using `jwt`?

EDIT:

The way of implementation I was thinking about is as follows:
- Username & password: Upon login, generate a token (using `jwt`) and send it to the client. Every request will include the token and the server will verify it.
- 3rd party provider: Let's say that the user is authenticated with `Facebook`. My server receive the token (using `passport-js`) from `Facebook`. Now I need to send the client its token. I could send the token I just received from facebook, but then how can I verify the token the client send to me afterward on every request?
So I could generate once again a token using `jwt` and work just like described above.

Is this a good implementation or am I missing something? I couldn't find 
a full tutorial that describe all of those aspects.

Comment: try to add more description about what you don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a token that an identity provider might give you, you might consider generating your own tokens based on a successful login callback to your application. Issue new tokens on every request for sliding expiration, and possibly consider the use of [refresh tokens](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/10/07/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/).

In your DB, you could store the authentication method for a given user (Facebook / Google / etc.) when they log in. When you receive a request with an invalid token, query for this auth method from the DB, then redirect them to the respective identity provider for re-authentication.

This will avoid DB lookups for most "normal" JWT validations for your app and gives you the full benefits of the stateless nature of the token.